# Why $http in angularJs can be treated as object and function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

$http service can be used in two different ways

> as a **function**, `var promise = $http(config);` where config object has information about http method and url etc

or

> as an **object**, `$http.get(url,config)`

I know functions in javascript are also objects...but I don't know how to create an object that can be used as a function call, can I achieve this using just javascript or it is something specific to angular?

Comment: Create a function and use it as an object. That's all there is to it. It has nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` itself is a function, and because functions are objects, they can attach extra properties to it.

It's not hard to do yourself either:

```js
var func = function() { alert("I am func"); };
func.prop = function() { alert("I am prop"); };

func();
func.prop();
```

Comment: can I add the property inside the function definition instead of doing to afterwards?

Comment: @watashiSHUN: Not really. The code within the function definition does not get run until the function is actually called, so putting anything in there wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first class objects in JavaScript, and so they can have properties too (and properties can be functions):

```
function T () {
    console.log("fired")
}

T.Prop = "SDLFKJ";

console.log(T.Prop);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xd39cyg3/)